# laravel equivalent order by random

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am beginner in Laravel.

I have project in Laravel 7.

I have this code:

```
public function getPromoProducts()
    {
        return $this->model->select('name', 'slug', 'products.id', 'small_description', 'promo_desc')->with(['features', 'frontImage'])->active()->leftJoin('selected_product_features', function ($join) {
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'selected_product_features.product_id');
        })->where('selected_product_features.key', 'price_promo')->where('selected_product_features.description', '<>', 0)->limit(2)->get();
    }
```

how can I make add to this code "ORDER BY RAND()" from traditional mysql?

Please help me

Comment: you can randomize the resultset after retreiving from the db with shuffle ( array &$array ). https://stillat.com/blog/2018/04/22/laravel-5-collections-randomizing-element-order-with-shuffle

Comment: try an inRandomOrder() before your ->get();

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has `inRandomOrder()` method, call it on the query builder. Down the hood it will use the [following](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5fc0ccde9b3cdbf7c9f2477e50521155445ec60e/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L101) for the ordering.

```
return $this->model->select('name', 'slug', 'products.id', 'small_description', 'promo_desc')
    ->with(['features', 'frontImage'])
    ->active()
    ->leftJoin('selected_product_features', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'selected_product_features.product_id');
    })->where('selected_product_features.key', 'price_promo')
    ->where('selected_product_features.description', '<>', 0)
    ->limit(2)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->get();
```

Comment: return $this->model->select('name', 'slug', 'products.id', 'small_description', 'promo_desc')
            ->with(['features', 'frontImage'])
            ->active()
            ->leftJoin('selected_product_features', function ($join) {
                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'selected_product_features.product_id');
            })
            ->where('promo_desc', '<>', 0)
            ->limit(2)
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->get(); - and it's work :) sometimes I have 2 duplicates product. Is posible repair it?

Comment: use distinct('products.id') would help i think